# Convert two columns into key-value json object?

Tags: sql-server, json, user-defined-functions, entity-attribute-value

Using `FOR JSON AUTO` or `FOR JSON PATH` on the following record set (which representing a product's attributes):

```
attribute | value
-----------------
color     | red
size      | small
```

will produce:

```
[{"attribute":"color","value":"red"},{"attribute":"size","value":"small"}]
```

Is there any way to produce the following Instead:

```
{"color":"red","size":"small"}
```

**Note** that as every product attribute is different than others; so this record set is different for every product. PIVOTing is not an option as it needs dynamic sql! Seems we need a function to be able to `CROSS` it with products table to produce for example a **product catalog**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of JSON functions of SQL Server 2016, I used [string concatenation function string_agg in SQL Server 2017](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/string-aggregation-function-to-concatenate-in-sql-server-2017.aspx) as seen in following script

```
/*create table ProductAttributes (
    product int,
    attribute varchar(40),
    value varchar(40)
)
insert into ProductAttributes select 1, 'color', 'red'
insert into ProductAttributes select 1, 'size', 'small'
insert into ProductAttributes select 2, 'processor', 'intel'
insert into ProductAttributes select 2, 'ram', '16'
insert into ProductAttributes select 2, 'weight', '2'*/

select 
    product, '{' + STRING_AGG( '"' + attribute + '":"' + STRING_ESCAPE(value,'json') + '"' ,',') + '}' as attributes
from ProductAttributes 
group by product
```

Output is as follows for the two product entries
product  attributes
1   {"color":"red","size":"small"}
2   {"processor":"intel","ram":"16","weight":"2"}

[image]

If you are using a previous version than SQL Server 2017, you can use [string concatenation using SQL XML Path](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/concatenate-using-xml-path.aspx) as follows

```
SELECT
    product,
  '{' + STUFF(
    (
    SELECT
      ',' + '"' + attribute + '":"' + STRING_ESCAPE(value,'json') + '"'
    FROM ProductAttributes a
        where a.product = p.product
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
    ).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'
    ), 1, 1, ''
  ) + '}' As attributes
from ProductAttributes p
group by product
```

Developers will get the same result

[image]

I've updated above SQL queries and used String_Escape() function @Eilert's comment

Comment: Sweet stuff! Nice workaround till microsoft adds an exclusive function to do so. Tanx.

Comment: I ran into an issue where the value I was trying to convert to json had special characters in it and that messed up the json. Conveniently I stumbled upon the STRING_ESCAPE function seemingly created just for this specific reason: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-escape-transact-sql

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, so it may be safer to replace "value"s in the code block with "STRING_ESCAPE(value,'json')"