# How to Use Select Value as Key for JSON in SQL

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a tsql stored procedure that generates a json file of the database I am working with. A certain part of the json file is an array of properties with a name, value, and requirement variable. This part of the JSON file looks like this:

```
"Properties": [
    {
        "PropertyName": "Foo"
        "PropertyValue": "Bar"
        "Required": "True"
    },
    {
        "PropertyName": "Foo2"
        "PropertyValue": "Bar2"
        "Required": "False"
    }
]
```

This is generated as a subquery of a larger SQL query that creates the entire JSON document:

```
SELECT,..., 
    (SELECT P.Name as PropertyName, P.Value as PropertyValue, P.Requirement as Required 
    FROM Properties P FOR JSON PATH) as Properties
FROM Foo
FOR JSON PATH
```

I want the JSON file to be laid out so the value of PropertyName is the key for the other two values:

```
"Properties" [
    {"Foo": {{"PropertyValue": "Bar"},{"Required": "True"}},
    etc.
]
```

Ideally the code could be something like:

```
(Select P.Value as [[P.Name].PropertyValue], P.Requirement as [[P.Name].Required]
 FROM Properties P 
 FOR JSON PATH)
```

But obviously that isn't a legal expression. Is there any way I can do this within an SQL framework or should I modify the file after it's created?

Comment: Not without some work, have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52973743/how-to-structure-json-sql-by-row-using-values-from-the-row/52976654#52976654

Comment: In general you should avoid to mix declarative parts (in this case the element's name) and values. Do you have a good reason to do this?